# How to Automatically Change a Cell in Google Sheets Based on Multiple Variables

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am working on creating a schedule in Google Sheets and I have just one last task that I cannot figure out. Here is an example of what I would like to accomplish.

For lines 8-12 (which is for Employees 1-5) I need to have a script that looks for every cell that contains either A or A-10. If these A or A-10 shifts fall on the 1-15 (days of the month are in row 5...pictured below) they should be changed to Aa or Aa-10. If they fall on the 16th-end of the month they should be Ap or Ap-10. The same will be the case with the R and I shifts.

Here is a screen shot of the Google Sheet from the example I gave above: 
[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a script that will do those changes. It only changes rows 8 - 12 and assumes the dates are in row 5.

```
function changeValues() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange("8:12");
  var dates = sheet.getRange("5:5").getValues();
  var values = range.getValues();
  for(var row = 0; row < values.length; row++) {
    for(var column = 1; column < values[row].length; column++) {
      var day = Number(dates[0][column].replace(/[^0-9]/g, ""));
      var value = values[row][column];
      if(day >= 1 && day <= 15) {
        if(value === "A") value = "Aa";
        else if(value === "A-10") value = "Aa-10";
      } else if(day > 15) {
        if(value === "A") value = "Ap";
        else if(value === "A-10") value = "Ap-10";
      }
      values[row][column] = value;
    }
  }
  range.setValues(values);
}
```

Comment: Wow. Awesome! Thank you so much. That is perfect!